# Database Error: Unable to connect to the database joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

im trying to set up a jommla site on wampserwer and i get a error

Database Error: Unable to connect to the database joomla

this is my first round with joomla and im not quite sure where is the problem

can you please give me some advice

i found in google some advice and i run a query in database :

SHOW PROCESSLIST;

and i get

5 |
root |
localhost:52664 |
mauriced_azurproductionvideo |
Query
0
init
SHOW PROCESSLIST

mayby it is a wrong port number ?

this is my configuration file:

```
   <?php
class JConfig {
    var $offline = '0';
    var $editor = 'tinymce';
    var $list_limit = '20';
    var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
    var $debug = '0';
    var $debug_lang = '0';
    var $sef = '0';
    var $sef_rewrite = '0';
    var $sef_suffix = '0';
    var $feed_limit = '10';
    var $feed_email = 'author';
    var $secret = '4UumITYjaQLXwKJS';
    var $gzip = '0';
    var $error_reporting = '-1';
    var $xmlrpc_server = '0';
    var $log_path = '/var/www/azurproductionvideo.com/logs';
    var $tmp_path = '/var/www/azurproductionvideo.com/tmp';
    var $live_site = '';
    var $force_ssl = '0';
    var $offset = '0';
    var $caching = '0';
    var $cachetime = '15';
    var $cache_handler = 'file';
    var $memcache_settings = array();
    var $ftp_enable = '0';
    var $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
    var $ftp_port = '21';
    var $ftp_user = '';
    var $ftp_pass = '';
    var $ftp_root = '';
    var $dbtype = 'mysql';
    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'root';
    var $db = 'mauriced_azurproductionvideo';
    var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
    var $mailer = 'mail';
    var $mailfrom = '';
    var $fromname = 'Azur Production Video';
    var $sendmail = '';
    var $smtpauth = '1';
    var $smtpsecure = 'tls';
    var $smtpport = '25';
    var $smtpuser = '';
    var $smtppass = '';
    var $smtphost = 'localhost';
    var $MetaAuthor = '1';
    var $MetaTitle = '1';
    var $lifetime = '15';
    var $session_handler = 'database';
    var $password = '';
    var $sitename = 'Azur Production Video';
    var $MetaDesc = 'Azur Production Video
Maurice Dray Nice';
    var $MetaKeys = 'Azur Production Video
Maurice Dray Paris france frenche riviera cote d\'azur, Cannes,Palm beach,Montleuze, Mont Leuze,barmitzvah,bar-mitzvah,Nice,video,montage,photo,photographe,mariage,ceremonie,synagogue,église,henné,infographie,sonorisation,clip,tirages papier,agrandissement,poster,aludibond,plexiglass,locatoin,vidéoprojection,cablages,micro,centre ville, louma, steadycam, prises de vues, photo,video,tournage,clip,montage,transcodage,intervieuw,mac,apple,asus,french riviera, cote d\'azur,nice,monaco,tr trop,saint tropez, montecarle,cafe de paris,palm beach,hermitage,domaine du montleuze,';
    var $offline_message = 'Ce site est en maintenance. Merci de revenir ultérieurement.';
}
?>
```

SOS! Some advice please.

Comment: Are you sure you typed in the correct database password? Did you also assign the database user to the database?

Comment: yes i know this is a bad practice to have a database without password and with root user, but this is just for test and the username is good and i don't have a password and it is not working i have other sites with the same configuration for user and password and it is working

Comment: in which case, simply create a new user with a password. Problem solved ;)

Comment: i did it and i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no password set for the root user in this config file.

I would also advise setting up a non root MySQL user.

In any chance, if you don't set the configuration file the Joomla! Installer should guide you through the process.

Comment: this is not a new installation site, this is a backap form server, i forgot to mention that sorry

Comment: No problem, have you downloaded and restored the database? Make sure root is assigned to that database. You may want to use the likes of akeeba backup which would implement an installer to allow you to restore the site simply. Setting it to zip archived will mean you can just unzip the archive and run the restore utility hen.

Comment: yes i downloaded the database and leather and restored in phpmyadmin, the root is in the list of users in database and hi dose not hava a password.Yes i unzipped the backup and it should work but i get a error

Comment: thanks for advice but i can't access a old version of site so i cannot install akeeba backup

Comment: yours answers whose all god this is my error, i didn't edit configuration file with administrator rights now it is working fine thanks everyone :)